# How to pass variable arguments to a Spark Dataframe using PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, variadic-functions

I am using the [Crealytics](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) Spark library to read an Excel Workbook into a Spark Dataframe using a Databricks Python notebook.

Hardcoded like this works fine:

```
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
     .option("useHeader","true")
     .option("dataAddress","'Sheet1'!")
     .load("/FileStore/tables/Test.xlsx")
```

I would like to read a dynamic list of options from a table into a PySpark structure (such as list or dict) and pass these to the DataFrame as varargs.

However, it fails even when trying to pass in just one option:

```
test = {"useHeader":"True"}

df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
     .option(*test)
     .option("dataAddress","'Sheet'!")
     .load("/FileStore/tables/Test.xlsx")
```

***TypeError: option() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)***

Answer (score 2):

Use [`options`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=options#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.options) not `option`

> `options(**options)`
>
> Adds input options for the underlying data source.

As you can see from the signature, it takes keyword arguments, hence dictionary unpacking will be a valid way to provide these.